# Setting MySql charsets

Tags: mysql, encoding, diacritics

I'm setting up my mysql installation (that still contains data).
The problem is: I setted utf8 in several settings, but still doesn't work fine.

MySql is xampp-managed, and these are settings

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                           |
| character_set_connection | utf8                           |
| character_set_database   | utf8                           |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8                           |
| character_set_server     | utf8                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I also edited my.ini:

```
## UTF 8 Settings
init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
```

My problem is accented words matches.
Actually, if I select a field, the accent is "?".

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: There's more to it than a bunch of settings within MySQL. The client (whatever connects to MySQL to insert data) also needs to handle data correctly. See the two linked duplicates/articles to get more background. If still necessary, add more information to your question to make it answerable.